# Clion cmake in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, clion

I've seen this one over and over but every answer that was given before didn't help me.
I downloaded clion and cmake, and updated gcc.
When manualy using gcc/g++ the code is compiling.
from the clion's cmake I keep getting:

```
CMake Error at /home/dm/Downloads/CLion-2018.1.4/clion-2018.1.4/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/gcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/dm/CLionProjects/TheTestingGrounds/cmake-build-default/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/local/bin/cmake" "cmTC_9582b/fast"
    CMake Error: The source directory "/home/dm/CLionProjects/TheTestingGrounds/cmake-build-default/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_9582b/fast" does not exist.
    Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Thing is, the cmTC_9582b/fast obviously dosen't exist. What is clion trying to do? It looks like it's trying to test cmake with a bad test and when its failing Clion decideds there's a problem.

Any solution for that?

Comment: If you try to manually call CMake on some test program, will it work?

(This output is generated by CLion that calls CMake on a test program to check the CMake+gcc/g++ environment is working)

Comment: I struggled with this for a few days - finally worked after a bit of hacking, can't remember all details, but essentially did an update, install gcc, install build-essential, which fixed your problem but then clion couldn't resolve std::cout, so  then the final fix was to delete the .CLion2018.1 directory in my home directory and rerun clion.  Good luck!

Comment: Here's a snipshot of my history with the things that seemed to lead to a solution:

  308  apt-get update

  309  sudo apt-get install gcc


  312  apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
...

  371  export CXX=/usr/bin/gcc
...

  378  yes | rm -r cmake-build-debug/
...

  440  yes | rm -r ./.CLion2018.1/